# Getting the row of the table cell that was just clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$('tbody').delegate('td','click',function() {
    log($(this).index()); // Column
});
```

Q: How do I determine the row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

```
$('tbody').delegate('td','click',function() {
  $(this).parent(); // tr
});
```

Or you can use:

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
  Traverse up the tree, starting at current element.
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
  Traverse up the tree starting with parent element.

Comment: `.parent()` should indeed be enough. Anything else would be malformed HTML.

Comment: @FelixKling: Malformed in what sense? -- EDIT: I also mention closest in case they want to bind to elements within the cell, but you're right about `.parent()` being precise from a cell itself.

Comment: I mean only a `tr` element can be a parent of a `td` element. So you can get the row by just calling `.parent()`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, smell what you're stepping in now.

Answer (score 2):

`parent()` is maybe what you are looking for. Like this:

`$(this).parent()`